# To check table schema change in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have a table in snowflake, I am inserting data from AWS job. before inserting data in snowflake I want to check if the number of columns and the data type of the inserting values are same as the snowflake table.

Comment: Could you explain why do you want to check the schema and why not build a table in snowflake based on your data and their types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What file type are you using?
Snowflake recently implemented schema detection feature which allows to detect schema of the files in the stage.
Note that this feature is currently limited to Apache Parquet, Apache Avro, and ORC files: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-overview.html#detection-of-column-definitions-in-staged-semi-structured-data-files

Comment: Thank you @ElenaG , I am using Apache Parquet files only. you made my task much easier.